# Simple way of reading a PDF, taking in text, and writing to a new PDF. (Java)

Tags: java, pdf, itext

***Disclaimer:*** I have been trying to do this with iText. I have read, studied, asked, queried, experimented, and did everything I could think of to make this work. I am infuriated. Please don't think I haven't tried and just came here so that I can get someone else to do this for me; that's not the case. I want to learn, I want to figure this out. I am looking for a good direction from someone that has experience with this.

I have a PDF that contains editable text fields. What I want to do is programmatically read from that PDF and take in the text from the text fields that are already there, take text from somewhere else in my app, and write the previous information + the new text information back to the original PDF.

What I have tried:
- reading the PDF with PdfReader
- using PdfStamper(PdfReader, FileOutputStream) to write to the PDF
- used reader.getAcroFields() to get the text fields.

I have scoured the web for days now and I can't get this to resolve. When I do this:

```
String in = "C:/Users/me/Desktop/file.pdf";
String out = "C:/Users/me/Desktop/file.pdf";
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(in);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(out));
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
form.setField("dateDisc1", "5/21");
```

it ends up creating a PDF (file.pdf) that is corrupted.

If there is an easier way to do this, please help me to shine some light on this.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried with different in/out file names, right?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo yea, I tried that. That's when it gave me a corrupt PDF that wouldn't open.

Comment: I don't see you closing the stamper. Have you simply forgotten to copy a final `stamper.close ()` into your question or is it really missing? In the latter case add it but do use different file names.

Comment: @mkl Figured it out on my own. I know you have helped me out a lot through this endeavor. See the answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out on my own. I created a walkthrough for others in the future looking to do something similar:

I have scoured the web for days trying to find a simple way of doing this. Unsuccessful, I dug my heels in and was determined that if it is possible, I will make it work. I have seen several dozen locations all over the internet of people asking how to do this; now, here is a well documented example.

```
//Define the location of the PDF and establish a new file to write to. We will change the target later//
    String dest = System.getProperty("user.home").concat("directory_and_name_of_PDF.pdf");
    String out = System.getProperty("user.home").concat("directory_and_name_that_will_be_changed.pdf");
    PdfReader pdfreader = new PdfReader(dest);                 
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfreader, new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.home").concat("same_as_String out")));       
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();  

//Append text to the text fields//
    form.setField("text field name", "text to add");
    form.setField("text field name2", "repeat");
    form.setField("text field name3", "repeat");
    form.setField("text field name4", "repeat");
    stamper.close();
    pdfreader.close();

//Change the file name of fileOutputStream to the original that was read from//
    File destfile = new File(dest);
    File outfile = new File(out);
    destfile.delete();        
    outfile.renameTo(new File(System.getProperty("user.home").concat("name_of_the_original_PDF.pdf")));
```

And there we have it. Be aware that this will delete the original file and rename the fileOutputStream to the original file name; if there was any information from the original that you didn't read in, it will be lost. Make sure to gather ALL of the information that you wish to copy over. Also, bear in mind that I set up a conditional statement (`if`) to make sure that whatever text in the text fields that was read in wouldn't be written over. You will have to do this or you risk not carrying over the previous text to the new PDF.

If there are any questions, feel free to ask. I am in no way a professional developer but I can offer advice on what I know. Remember to research before you ask. Good luck!

Comment: I migrated your solution from your question (which wasn't really a question) into the body of the answer here, where it belongs. It's perfectly fine to write an answer to your own question, and in fact we encourage that if you're able to shed new light on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah Sorry, I didn't notice the filenames.

**Original answer:**

Okay there is no simple way, I found this out many moons ago.

PDF is actually some sort of wrapper around PostScript (it contains fonts and such), and converting PDF to PostScript is very easy (I just ran a command and worked on the PostScript from there)

It's not like LaTeX, PostScript is for printers, and it has a stack where you can push states and such, every letter is positioned absolutely, PostScript is a set of instructions for a virtual machine the printer then interprets.

Text highlighing and such comes from a higher up knowledge that the text flows from left to right and stuff. I read the PostScript standard, got what I wanted and have not touched it since, this isn't a great anwer but will certainly point you in the right direction.

Remember PDFs and PostScript(document)s are not made to be edited, they don't do text-wrap and such, if you zoom you have to pan, they exist to preserve the format, for printers and such.

Comment: @Smit Figured it out on my own. Thank you for the helpful input, though. See the answer.